# bash : displaying null value for a variable after "for loop" execution with below code

Tags: braces

creating a variable from a "for a loop" and then assining a string to 
it.New value is showing as null.
expected output : 
colname1=hash(id) as id
colname2=hash(cust) as cust

Actual output :
colname1=' '
colname2=' '

```
#!/bin/bash
hcd1="hash("           # string to be added
hcd2=")as "            #string to be added 
dmk=id,cust
IFS=" ,"
i=0
for val in ${dmk}
do
  i=$((++i))
  eval var${i}="${val}"
done
for ((j=1;j<=i;++j))
do
  name="var${j}"
  colname="col${j}"
  echo ${colname} = "$hcd1${!name}$hcd2 ${!name}"
done
echo "$colname1    $colname2 "
```

Answer (score 0):

some notes:

- ${dmk} doesn't expand commas. your loop would be: of one element: 'id,cust'
- you don't need curly braces to interpolate variables ${dmk} is the same as $dmk
- ${!name} seems invalid. probably you have meant   $name

with some corrections

```sh
#!/bin/bash
hcd1="hash("           # string to be added
hcd2=")as "            #string to be added 
dmk="id cust"
#IFS=" ,"
i=0
for val in $dmk
do
  i=$((++i))
  eval var$i="$val"
  #echo  var$i="$val"
done
for ((j=1;j<=i;++j))
do
  eval name='$'"var$j"
  colname="col$j"
  echo $colname = "$hcd1$name$hcd2 $name"
done
```

**outputs**:

```
col1 = hash(id)as  id
col2 = hash(cust)as  cust
```

Comment: Thanks Phil . script  is working but when i execute "echo  $col1   $col2" , i am not getting the desired output. variable col1 has to be displayed as "hash(id)as  id"    and variable col2 as "hash(cust)as  cust"     i am getting below error: stock.sh: line 17: col1: command not found
stock.sh: line 17: col2: command not found

Comment: It seems you have windows file endings . Try to convert e scrip with dos2unix. And you still have the issue paste it here

Comment: i converted script using dos2unix but still same issue.getting null values for variables col1 and col2

Comment: command issued :   echo "first column col1 :${col1} "    got output  as :     first column col1 :

Comment: That's because the col1 variable was never set. By using eval the variables var1 is set to id, and var2 to customer.

Comment: It seems you want to generate some SQL statements like table create from a list of fields. Or rather format the list of fields for each value.

Comment: you are exactly right , Phil. i am trying to g  enerate SQL statement.   I am getting same issue even after executing your code.I am clue less what exactly is happening. i have been working on this issue for last three days still not able to solve the issue.    can you please provide  me code where we can  "hash(id)as id "  if we issue command like   echo $col1.

Comment: That can be done much simpler. You have to the field definitions in the first loop. For example: for v in id cust other; echo " hash($v) as $v "; done